# How do I use LINQ to filter AND manipulate results based on values intersecting between a child and comparer?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Thanks for looking!

## Background

I am writing in C# and using LINQ to query entities for a report.  In this report, I have a set of entities that basically look like this:

```
Customer{
       Name: "Bob",
       ProductsPurchased: ArrayOfChildEntities[{
             ProductId: 1,
             ProductTypeId: 5,
             ProductName: "FooBuzz"
          },
          {...},
          {...}]
}
```

`ProductsPurchased` is an array of child entities that contain a product type id.  Let's say that I pass in an array of type ids that the user chose from a filter list in the view:

`var ProductTypesToShow = [1, 3, 5];`

So for each customer returned, I want to show only the products they have purchased that are of type `1`,`3`, or `5`.  *If a customer has never purchased at least one product of type `1`,`3`, or `5`, then that entire customer object should be removed from the result set.*

## What I have tried

I have tried using something like this:

```
var customers = db.Customers.Where(c => c.ProductsPurchased.Select(p => ProductTypesToShow.Contains(p.ProductTypeId));
```

But this fails.  I have also tried various versions of `Intersect` and `Any` but unfortunately they all fail for one reason or another, or they fail to do all of the things I need:

1. Select only customers who have purchased a product of type `1`,`3`, or `5`.
2. Of those customers, remove any products not of type `1`,`3`, or `5` before sending the data back to the view.

Finally, I wrote a `foreach` monstrosity that iterates all customers found in an initial query and then iterates their products to filter by product type, but this was unacceptably slow (about 3 minutes per query!!).

I feel like I must be missing something obvious here.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how to make it work without some experimenting, but have you played with `Join` at all?

Comment: I haven't but will.  Oddly, I am only recently discovering how powerful `Join` can be in LINQ.

Comment: Maybe you should create SQL query first, and then try translate it into LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say if it's gonna work with LINQ to Entities, but I would try that one:

```
var results = (from c in customers
               select new 
                   {
                       Name = c.Name,
                       Products = c.ProductsPurchased.Where(p => ProductTypesToShow.Contains(p.ProductTypeId))
                   } into c2
               where c2.Products.Any()
               select new
                   {
                       Name = c2.Name,
                       Products = c2.Products.ToArray()
                   }).ToArray();
```

It should return an array of anonymous type with 2 properties: `Name` and `Products`.

Comment: Thank you, I converted this to a Lambda, but the answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it in LinqToSql.  I'm unsure if LinqToEntities supports Contains.

```
List<int> ProductTypesToShow = new List<int>() {1,3,5};

IQueryable<Product> productQuery = dc.Products
  .Where(p => ProductTypesToShow.Contains(p.ProductTypeId));  //deferred

var customerProductQuery =
  from c in dc.Customers
  join p in productQuery on c.CustomerID equals p.CustomerID into g //groupjoin!
  where g.Any()
  select new {Customer = c, Products = g.ToList()}; //customers with their products. deferred

List<Customer> result = new List<Customer>();

foreach(var pair in customerProductQuery)  //query executed
{  //manual result shaping
  Customer resultItem = pair.Customer;
  resultItem.Products = pair.Products;
  result.Add(resultItem);
}

return result;
```

Comment: Yes, LINQ to Entities support `Contains` and translates it into `IN` SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks.  It is helpful that you added the comments about what is deferred and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = customers
.Where(cust=>cust.ProductsPurchased.Any(ProductsToShow.Contains))
.Select(cust=>new{
           cust.Name,
           Purchases=cust.ProductsPurchased.Where(ProductsToShow.Contains)
    });
```